# Create an algorithm to determine if a Context Free Grammar can generate the empty word(ε)

Tags: algorithm, context-free-grammar

I am trying to create an algorithm to decide the following decidable problem: Given a CFG H, does  H ⇒*ε. That is can H generate the empty word in any amount of steps. The algorithm has to be decidable which means it always halts on all inputs correctly.

I've been looking at this problem for quite some time and don't even know how to start or the steps to create this algorithm. I'm not looking for the whole answer, I just need a push in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

If you convert this grammar to Chomsky Normal Form using a normal algorithm to do so, there will come a point where it becomes clear whether the start symbol of your grammar is capable of deriving the empty string. This is because you will iteratively remove all productions that generate the empty string until you find (or fail to find) the necessary production.

Comment: @jippy You are asked for an algorithm, which I take to mean that it should work for *any* CFG provided as input. There is no specific grammar to work with. When designing an algorithm, it can definitely be helpful to have several representative inputs in mind, but you have to decide what those are yourself.

Comment: (In other words, a perhaps slightly modified version of a process to convert CFGs to CNF is an answer to your question; the process itself, not the result of applying that process to any particular CFG)